# Realm Object fields are nil sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm having a strange issue with objects in Realm. When I fetch an object from Realm database sometimes some of its fields (it only happens on `RealmOptionals`) are nil after accessing them.

But it's really weird because if I put a breakpoint before the access to that fields and I execute `po object.field` on `lldb` the nil fields are gone after that.
I have seen that maybe I have forgot to set that fields as ´dynamic´ but in my case, and following Realm docs, I have to use RealmOptional for optional booleans.

Does anyone know what's the issue here?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The method that I used to retrieve and object from Realm is:

```
    func getObject(atPosition position:Int)->Object{
        let objects = realm.objects(Object.self)
        return objects[position]
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. If a Realm property is marked optional, then its initial value will be `nil` as expected.

You're correct in that you need to use `let propertyValue = RealmOptional<Bool>()` instead of `dynamic` as normal boolean data types can't express a `nil` value on their own. So this is an exception to the `dynamic` properties rule.

Also be aware you need to use `optional.value` to set an optional Bool's value:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    let vaccinated = RealmOptional<Bool>()
}

let realm = try! Realm()

let myDog = Dog()
myDog.name = "Sherlock Bones"
myDog.age = 4
myDog.vaccinated.value = true

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(myDog)
}
```

Comment: I've just observe that It's not only with RealmOptional, but with dynamic strings too. I updated the question with a piece of code where I retrieve an element from Realm. Thank you very much TiM for helping me in both questions. You and the Realm team are f***ing awesome!

Comment: I edited your answer because you put me in the right direction. Thank you for your time, I appreciate your help.